# How can I get the numeric value from an array?

Tags: php

I have this following segment in my array.

```
[genres] => Array
    (
        [0] => Adventure
        [1] => Drama
        [2] => Game
        [3] => Harem
        [4] => Martial Arts
        [5] => Seinen
    )
```

I am trying to return each of those elements separately.

```
foreach($t['genres'] as  $tag=>$value) {
    // I don't know what to do from here
}
```

Can someone help me on how I can print each unique value?

Comment: `echo $value;` would be a start...

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You're go through each element, $tag - is array key, $value - value)))

Comment: you can start on `echo $tag . " => " . $value . "\n";`

Comment: You want to get index of items?

Comment: There is no numeric **value** in your array. You have numeric keys. Is that what you are looking for? Keys are always unique so your question make very little sense. Can you show us what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`genres` is an [associative array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm) meaning that the key will only give you the index point of that value. Your values are of type String, not numerical values.

```
$genres = ['Adventure', 'Drama', 'Game', 'Harem', 'Martial Arts', 'Seinen'];
```

So in this case, at index point 0 (arrays start at 0), we will get Adventure.

```
[0] => Adventure
```

To get these values out of the array one by one you can do this:

```
foreach($genres as $_genre) {
    echo $_genre;
}
```

To get these values and/or keys from the array one by one you can do this:

```
foreach($genres as $_key => $_genre) {
    echo "Index: {$_key} - Value: {$_genre}"
}
```

Keys are numerical values, they mark the point of the value in that array. For example, if we wanted to get `Game` from the array:

```
[2] => Game
```

We can see that it has an index of 2 and can be called like:

```
echo $genres[2];
```